# Regex "AND" Operator?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

 Source Path: \build\PM\11.0.25.9\11025_0_X.pts Destination Path:

I want to cut off the strings "Source Path:" and "Destination Path:" in order to get only the source path.

 I figured to do this would be to do a simple `Regex.Replace`.

However i'm not sure of how exactly one would write a pattern that would look for both of these strings.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a Regex, you can just simply do a `Replace`:

```
var path = "Source Path: \build\PM\11.0.25.9\11025_0_X.pts Destination Path:"
    .Replace("Source Path: ", "")
    .Replace(" Destination Path:", "");
```

Comment: And if destination path isn't empty?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps something that doesn't use replace:

```
string s = "Source Path: \build\PM\11.0.25.9\11025_0_X.pts Destination Path:";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, "^Source Path:\s(.*?)\sDestination Path:$");
string result = string.Empty;
if (m.Success)
{
    result = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string is always in the same format and you don't have spaces in your path, you can use string split in conjunction with the `Skip` and `First` IEnumerable extensions.

```
var input = @"Source Path: \build\PM\11.0.25.9\11025_0_X.pts Destination Path:";
var path = input.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Skip(2)
                .First();
```

Comment: Minor note. Your input string needs an @ to prevent the backslashes from being used as escape codes. Edit: I see all responses have this mistake. Oh well. :-)